# Set an element of an array of pointers to a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Vector {
public: 
    double *array;
    int width;
    Vector (int width) {
        array = new double[width];
        this->width = width;    
    }
    double& operator[] (int x) {
        return this->array[x];    
    }
}; 


class Matrix {
public:
    double *array;
    int height;
    int width; 
    Matrix (int height, int width) {
        array = new double[height * width];    
        this->height = height;
        this->width = width; 
    }
    Vector& operator[] (int x) {
        Vector v = Vector(this->width);     
        for (int i = 0; i < this->width; i++) {
            // ERROR!
            &(v.array + i) = &this->array[x * this->height + i];
        }
        return v;
    }
};

int main() {
    // vec
    Vector vec = Vector(2);
    vec[0] = 2; 
    cout<<vec.array[0]<<endl; // Prints 2, Correct
    // mat
    Matrix mat = Matrix(3,2);
    mat[2][0] = 4;
    cout<<mat.array[6]<<endl; // Must be 4
    // 6 = y * height + x
    // 6 = 2 * 3 + 0
    // 6 = 6
}
```

I want to initialize an array of pointers, then set one of the elements of the array to another pointer (this is shown in my matrix class in `operator[]`). I want to do this because it removes the need of writing lines of code like this: `mat.array[...]`. I would much rather use `mat[...][...]`.

I have tried declaring my `array` variable in my `Vector` class as a reference: `double &array;`. Sadly I can’t do this because my `array` variable depends on a parameter in the constructor `int width`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your matrix class should contain a "Vector* array;" instead of a "double *array;"

Comment: It's hacky, but the simplest solution would be for your `operator[]` to return `double*` and simply return `array + x*width`, this way you will be able to use `mat[x][y]`.  Or you would need to construct a class that will be a view of data, without owning it (your `Vector` owns its data).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen good suggestion, but let’s say I want to run the code `a[3] = {2,3,4}` where `a` is a matrix. I can’t do this unless I declare an operator= *in the double* class, using the `extension` keyword. I want to refrain from doing this because this is already declared in my `Vector` class

Comment: However, @SvenNilsson put up a great suggestion, and honestly, I can’t believe I didn’t think of this before! Not only this will fix my problem, it will make development of the Matrix class a lot smoother. Thanks to both of your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you simply want to access the elements of matrix as martrix[a][b] and not matrix.array[a].

First thing first, your `operator[]()` is inefficient.

1. It won't be able to handle the cases of matrix with width other than 2.

   To correct that, you need to change

   `Vector v = new Vector(2);`

   to

   `Vector v = new Vector(width);`
2. You are making a new Vector each time the operator is called.

Instead you can follow the below suggestion.

1. Change `double* array` in Matrix class to `Vector* array`
2. Matrix Constructor to

   ```
   Matrix(int _height , int _width) : height(_height), width(_width) {
        array = new Vector[height];  // new Vector(width)[height] does not work. Someone, please check. Till then give a default value in Vector constructor to make that work
        for(int i=0;i<height;++i) {
            array[i] = Vector(width);
        }
    }
   ```
3. `operator[]()` in Matrix class to

   ```
   Vector& operator[](int x) {
       return array[x];
   }
   ```

Comment: I will update `Vector v = new Vector(width)` now, thanks for spotting that.